# How to turn off selection cells by tab and shif+tab in QTableWidget in slot?

Tags: c++, qt

I turn on editing some columns of QTableWidget by this

```
QObject::connect(ui->tableWidgetAdminEmployee, &QTableWidget::clicked,
                     ui->tableWidgetAdminEmployee, [=](const QModelIndex& index) {
if(index.column()!=0&&index.column()!=7&&index.column()!=8&&index.column()!=9)
   if (ui->tableWidgetAdminEmployee->item(index.row(), index.column())->flags() & Qt::ItemIsEnabled )
       ui->tableWidgetAdminEmployee->edit(index);
    });
```

But if i choose editable cell and then start editing it and press tab next cell will be selected and become editable even if it shouldn't

I turned off tabKeyNavigation in QTableWidget, but non-editable cells still can be selected by tab

I tryed this but didn't help

```
QObject::connect(ui->tableWidgetAdminEmployee, &QTableWidget::clicked,
                 ui->tableWidgetAdminEmployee, [=](const QModelIndex& index) {
if(index.column()!=0&&index.column()!=7&&index.column()!=8&&index.column()!=9)
{
    if (ui->tableWidgetAdminEmployee->item(index.row(), index.column())->flags() & Qt::ItemIsEnabled )
       ui->tableWidgetAdminEmployee->edit(index);
}
else
       ui->tableWidgetAdminEmployee->item(index.row(), index.column())->setFlags(Qt::ItemIsEnabled);
    });
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not editable cell"? It seems you handle "editable" by yourself in the `clicked` singal by checking columns. Do you set the cells's flags to not include `Qt::ItemIsEditable`?

Comment: All columns in QTableWidget is editable except columns 0,7,8,9. If i choose cell in column 6  witch is editable and press tab then i will be able to edit cell in column 7 which shouldn't happen

Comment: Do you mean like this if(index.column()!=0&&index.column()!=7&&index.column()!=8&&index.column()!=9 && index.flags().testFlag(Qt::ItemIsEditable))? I tryed didn't help

Comment: No, I mean do you somewhere call `itm->setFlags(...)` with a flag that does not include `Qt::ItemIsEditable`? Or any edit triggers? Your code for the clicked signal just handles that: a click event. It doesn't handle "editing" events in general

Comment: No i don't call this, all my code about editing is attached to question

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to handle editing by yourself. This can be a valid approach.

However, you need to disable Qt's default editing capabilities. For your case, I guess turning off all editing triggers is the easiest way (cf [edit triggers](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qabstractitemview.html#editTriggers-prop))

```
ui->tableWidgetAdminEmployee->setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView::NoEditTriggers);
```

Thus Qt will in no way start editing by itself, and you have full control.

Comment: Didn't help, cells are still editable by tab

Answer (score 0):

Solved

```
        for(int row=0; row<ui->tableWidgetAdminEmployee->rowCount(); row++){
        for(int col=0; col< ui->tableWidgetAdminEmployee->columnCount(); col++){
            auto item=new QTableWidgetItem;
            if(col==0 || col==7 || col==8|| col==9)
                item->setFlags(item->flags() &  ~Qt::ItemIsEditable); //non-editable columns
            ui->tableWidgetAdminEmployee->setItem(row, col, item);
        }
    }
    
    ui->tableWidgetAdminEmployee->setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::NoSelection);
    ui->tableWidgetAdminEmployee->setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView::NoEditTriggers);

    QObject::connect(ui->tableWidgetAdminEmployee, &QTableWidget::clicked,
                     ui->tableWidgetAdminEmployee, [=](const QModelIndex& index) {

        if (ui->tableWidgetAdminEmployee->item(index.row(), index.column())->flags() & Qt::ItemIsEditable )
            ui->tableWidgetAdminEmployee->edit(index);
    });
```